# how to count number of sprites swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, enumeration

I'm building an app that add sprites to the screen.
In several parts of my code I want to know how many sprites I have with a certain key.
At the moment I implemented it in this way

```
var counter = 0
enumerateChildNodesWithName("box") { node, _ in
  counter = counter + 1
}
println(counter)
```

Is there another easier and shorter way?
Thanks

Comment: Minor points: `node, _` could be `_, _` and `counter = counter + 1` could be `counter++` .

Comment: You're doing it right. The only other alternative would be "reference counting", ie whenever you add a sprite you increase a counter value, if you remove one you decrease the value. It's best to route all add/remove through a single method so that you never miss or forget to change the counter. Still that solution is potentially brittle.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D I think you are right, since I have a method for the generation and another one for the destruction the best way is to use just ++ and -- and than ask for the value when I need it.

Comment: @MartinR Thank you. Actually it's not clear to me the syntax that I have to use after that method...but it works anyway

Comment: `self["box"].count` doesn't work?

Comment: @rintaro where do I have to put that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**From iOS8**, `SKNode` has `subscript` member that queries nodes and returns `Array<SKNode>`.

```
extension SKNode {
    subscript (name: String) -> [SKNode] { get }
}
```

So you can:

```
let count = self["box"].count
println(count)
```

instead of:

```
var counter = 0
self.enumerateChildNodesWithName("box") { _, _ in
    counter += 1
}
println(counter)
```

Comment: At the moment I found a workaround as LearnCocos2D suggested, but thank you for your answer helped me understand swift a bit better.

Comment: @Nicholas this answer is a better solution that doesn't require you to maintain a count of the nodes in the scene. You can even search the node tree with `"//box"`.

Comment: @0x141E can you give me a simple snippet for that?

Comment: `let count = self["//box"]` provides a count of all nodes and descendants of nodes in the scene named "box"