# Swift: typecasting in a for loop

Tags: for-loop, swift, casting, sprite-kit, sknode

I'm a noobie in Swift. I'm trying to iterate over SKNodeTree and check if there are scary monster Nodes here. However I cannot figure out how to typecase the for loop. I have understood that this would be possible with "as" clause.

By the way, is comparing strings with == ok in Swift?

```
      for monsterNode in self.children{
          if (monsterNode.name? == "scary") {
                println("scary monster here")
          }
      }
```

Comment: See [how to count number of sprites swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27201797/how-to-count-number-of-sprites-swift) for an easier solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comparing strings can be done by using == instead of isEqualToString, so thats fine. Your code should be like this:

```
for monsterNode in self.children as [SKNode] {
    if (monsterNode.name? == "scary") {
          println("scary monster here")
    }
}
```

You can submit your cast inside the brackets []